# JavaScript security alert from Github for R user

Tags: javascript, r, github, npm, gruntjs

I use R and am not familiar with JavaScript.
Recently, Github sent a security alert:

[image]

This relates to the R package, "sparkline".
Github says, "We found potential security vulnerabilities in your dependencies." and mentions this file: static/rmarkdown-libs/jquery-sparkline/package.json

```
{
  "name": "Sparkline",
  "title": "jQuery Sparkline",
  "description": "Easily generate small, inline sparkline charts directly in the browser",
  "keywords": ["canvas", "charts", "graphics", "graphing", "graphs", "sparklines", "ui", "vml"],
  "banner": "/* jquery.sparkline 2.1.3 - http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/ \n Licensed under the New BSD License - see above site for details */\n",
  "version": "2.1.4",
  "repository": "git@github.com:relayfoods/jquery.sparkline.git",
  "author": {
    "name": "Gareth Watts",
    "url": "http://gwatts.com/"
  },
  "licenses": [{
    "type": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "url": "http://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause"
  }],
  "bugs": "https://github.com/gwatts/jquery.sparkline/issues",
  "homepage": "http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/",
  "demo": "http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/",
  "docs": "http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/#s-docs",
  "download": "http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/#s-download",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": ">=2.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.11.3",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.9.2",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.6.1",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.5.1"
  }
}
```

I tried updating my JavaScript packages with:

```
npm i -g npm-check-updates
npm install
```

But that had no effect on Github's warning message.
I believe that v2.0 of the "sparkline" package is the most recent from CRAN and Github.

Can I fix this or does it have to be done by the sparkline maintainer?

Comment: Is this a package you wrote? Or why do you have the source code for this package on github? Does your `package.json` file change at all? Have you tried running `npm outdated`? That package doesn't seem to have been updated in quite a while.

Comment: I did not write the package. A common R way to publish a website is RStudio > Rmarkdown > Github > Netlify. npm outdated has no output.